# Adding geometry to THREE.Object3D

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've edited this post to make it more clear.

Well, What I am trying to do here is to represent a tile composed by 8 different triangles. Each triangle should be able to change it color independently.

[image: The initial state of the tile]

So, the problem I'm having is that when I change the color of a single triangle it changes the color of the lines in betwen, as you can see in the second image.

[image: Update state of the tile]

This is the code to create a tile:

```
var tile=[];
var n=0;
for(var i=0; i<4; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<2; j++){
        var triangle = new THREE.Object3D();
        var lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color:0xffffff, transparent:true, opacity:0.5});
        var triangleMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:COLOR_OFF ,emissive:EMISSIVE_OFF ,side:THREE.DoubleSide, shading:THREE.FlatShading});

        var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        geometry.vertices.push( triangleVectors[j][0], triangleVectors[j][1], triangleVectors[j][2] );
        var face = new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2);
        geometry.faces.push(face);

        triangle.add(new THREE.LineSegments(new THREE.Geometry(), lineMaterial));
        triangle.add( new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.Geometry(), triangleMaterial));

        triangle.children[ 0 ].geometry = new THREE.WireframeGeometry(geometry);
        triangle.children[ 1 ].geometry = geometry;

        triangle.rotation.z = Math.PI*i/2;
        triangle.position.x = TILE_LENGTH*x;
        triangle.position.y = TILE_LENGTH*y;

        n++;                        
        tile.push({'triangle':triangle,'number':n,'state':"OFF"});                      
        scene.add(triangle);
     }
}
```

To update the state of a triangle of the Tile I'm using this code:

```
for(var j=0;j<tile.length; j++){

    tile[j].triangle.children[0].material.color.set(COLOR_OFF);
    tile[j].triangle.children[1].material.color.set(COLOR_OFF);
    tile[j].state="OFF";

    for(var k=0; k<pathUpdates[step].length; k++){
        if(pathUpdates[step][k].number == tile[j].number){
           tile[j].triangle.children[0].material.color.set(COLOR_ON);               
           tile[j].triangle.children[1].material.color.set(COLOR_ON);
           floor[i].tile[j].state="ON";
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to change to modifie a material?

I simplifyed a little bit the code to show better my issue. However, the real code is in this repository https://github.com/tul1/Tile.git . If you want to take a look at it working I deployed it in http://tul1.github.io/examples/dale.html .

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here. `THREE.Object3D` can be used to group objects, but there's also the more syntactically-specific `THREE.Group` object. The actual objects which contain your geometry (and materials) are the `LineSegments` and `Mesh` objects. I also don't understand why you're `dispose`ing, and then re-setting the geometry, but perhaps we can revisit that if you can provide some more details about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Mesh already extends Object3D

Comment: i rewrite the post to make more clear my issue. thnx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So, the problem I'm having is that when I change the color of a single triangle it changes the color of the lines in between, as you can see in the second image.

I looked at your source code, and if all you want to do is *not* affect the color of the lines in between so that they remain white, simply remove the line that changes the color of `lineMaterial`:

```
for(var j=0;j<tile.length; j++){
    // The line below changes all line colors to 0x156289:
    // tile[j].triangle.children[0].material.color.set(COLOR_OFF);

    tile[j].triangle.children[1].material.color.set(COLOR_OFF);
    tile[j].state="OFF";

    for(var k=0; k<pathUpdates[step].length; k++){
        if(pathUpdates[step][k].number == tile[j].number){
           // The line below changes the active line color to 0x891528
           // tile[j].triangle.children[0].material.color.set(COLOR_ON); 

           tile[j].triangle.children[1].material.color.set(COLOR_ON);
           floor[i].tile[j].state="ON";
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

If you don't touch the color on the lines, they'll remain white as when you first created them:
[image]

**Grouping**

If you want to group all tiles into one object, you should declare a [THREE.Group object](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/objects/Group) in your global scope (outside all the `for()` loops). Then you can add each triangle individually in each iteration of the `for()` loop. Here's some pseudocode on how to achieve this:

```
// Create tileGroup outside the loop
var tileGroup = new THREE.Group();

for(var x=0; x<nX; x++){
    for(var y=0; y<nY; y++){
        var tile=[];
        var n=0;
        for(var i=0; i<4; i++){
            for(var j=0; j<2; j++){
                // All your existing triangle-creation code goes in here

                // ...

                // After triangle has been created, we add triangle
                // to group, instead of adding it to scene
                tileGroup.add(triangle);
            }
        }
    }
}

// Finally, we add tileGroup to scene
scene.add(tileGroup);

// Now we can manipulate all tiles at once within the group
tileGroup.position.set(0, 15, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that resolved the problem. I do have another question concerning this problem. Is there a way to group all these triangles in the same THREE object? Of course, without losing their independency to change the material.

Comment: Sure. Answering two questions in one post is kind of frowned upon in StackOverflow, but I edited my original answer to add a section on grouping the triangles into one `Group` object.

Comment: thanx mate, you are my hero :-)